# How can I do a UNION operation with DexieJS?

Tags: dexie

I have a `indexedDB` with `firstName` and `lastName` as columns.

Here is some sample data:

```
firstName lastName
__________________
John Doe  
Mary Doe  
Jacob Adams
Doe Mary
```

When I search for `Doe`, the query should return the **first two entries and the last**. If I search for `Jacob`, it should return the **second last**.

I followed examples from this [Dexie](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/blob/master/samples/codeproject-article/DexieAlgorithmsSamples.html) sample, but I can't do a single search on two fields at the same time. If not, is there a way to run two questions and UNION the results to a single one?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this:

```
table.where('firstName').equals('Doe').or('lastName').equals('Doe')
```